# Firebase database not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an app that requires Firebase auth and database. When registering, the app must check to see if the code entered is genuine then proceed to create a user. This is my code:

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    self.ref.child("PatientCodes").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snaphshot) in
        print("In")
        let value = snaphshot.value as! NSArray

        if value.contains(self.patientIDTextField.text!) {
            print("Found ID")

            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
                if user != nil {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registered", sender: self)
                }
            })

        }
```

The issue I am having is, none of the code is being executed past `self.ref.child` etc. The `print("In")` statement is never hit.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your Firebase JSON structure on which you are running the above query.

Comment: I can not show that data, it is confidential to the client, but, the parent is "PatientCodes", and the children are listed under that.

Comment: @EvanRey please study [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which explains the need and value of having a minimal reproduction of the problem.

Comment: But a `.value` event should always fire, event when there's no value. The only reason that comes to mind is that you're not connected to the Firebase backend. Are you sure the phone is connected to the network?

Comment: Yes. I am certain it is connected. Sign in and out work but for some reason that will not.

Comment: Im having the same issue! Non of the callback blocks get called. Still havent found a solution

Comment: @Zolve, I figured out the issue and felt so stupid when I did so. You have to go to firebase.google.com and change the read and write to anyone opposed to requiring authentication.

Comment: Cheers @EvanRey but that wasnt the issue for me. The issue for me was i wasnt logged in before making requests to the database. I thought i was authenticated because `currentUser.id` existed but it was cached from when i had logged in earlier.

Comment: @Zolve, how did you end up forcing a refresh for the logged in user?

Comment: @MacLean if theres no current user just call `FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn()` to just sign in again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your database's rules, the default rule prevents anonymous read and write, so you must log in first to get access to the database.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before starting anything with `Firebase Database`,
first check that the rules under database in your console is properly set i.e whether read is `true` or write is `true`.